# Python: turn json result in DataFrame

Tags: python

I need to extract latitude and longitude by API, it's done but I want to extract both `lat` and `lon` only. Below was the code and result:

**Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

#Read building file csv (in utf-8)
df=pd.read_csv('Building(LocationIQ).csv')

#API call and get lat long value
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    
    apiAddress = str(df.at[i,'Address'])

    url = "https://us1.locationiq.com/v1/search"
    
    data = {
        'key': '******************',
        'q': apiAddress,
        'format': 'json',
        'limit': 1
    }
    
    response = requests.get(url, params=data)
    
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    
    print(data)
```

---

**Result:**

```
[{
    'place_id': '111603517',
    'licence': 'https://locationiq.com/attribution',
    'osm_type': 'way',
    'osm_id': '23426070',
    'boundingbox': ['-34.8580617', '-34.8540045', '138.5041642', '138.5089397'],
    'lat': '-34.8561867',
    'lon': '138.5063104',
    'display_name': 'Webb Street, Port Adelaide, Adelaide, City of Port Adelaide Enfield, South Australia, 5015, Australia',
    'class': 'highway',
    'type': 'tertiary',
    'importance': 0.5
}]
```

I've tried code like `pd.read_json` and `json_normalize` but they both failed.

Comment: What happens if you use this command? `df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latitude and longitude of this dictionary, try:

```py
print(data[0].get("lat"))
print(data[0].get("lon"))
```

This gets the first dictionary in your list of data, and prints both the latitude and longitude of the structure.
There is only one item in your list so I'm presuming this is what you wanted.

`dict.get` returns `None` by default if the item is not found so you may want to add a check for that if it is not guaranteed to be there.

To turn this into a pandas DataFrame, you should be able to do:

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    "lat": data[0].get("lat"),
    "lon": data[0].get("lon"),
})
```

And to add this to an existing DataFrame:

```py
df.append({
    "lat": data[0].get("lat"),
    "lon": data[0].get("lon"),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question what the desired end goal is. Assuming that you want to add 2 new columns to your existing dataframe, called "lat" and "lon", you could do this:

```
url = "https://us1.locationiq.com/v1/search"

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    apiAddress = str(df.at[i,'Address'])
    data = {
        'key': '******************',
        'q': apiAddress,
        'format': 'json',
        'limit': 1
    }
    response = requests.get(url, params=data)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    if data:
        df.loc[i, 'lat'] = data[0].get('lat')
        df.loc[i, 'lon'] = data[0].get('lon')
```

Comment: Hi justauser,

Thanks. I've try your code and it did retrieve the info but with a Keyerror: 0.  Is it due to no lat long can be found from that row ? I try include default value as "NA" or 0 but still not work.

Comment: @ThomasWong,  Keyerror: 0 means that data is an empty list (ie the API returned a blank response). `data[0]` fails, as there is no object at index 0 in the list. I've updated the answer to check if data has content.